# Django Serve Special files like favicon and manifest

Tags: python, django

How can I serve a directory as the default in Django?

I build a django/react application.  Got it all set up with uWSGI.  Static files for both react and django working (using whitenoise for multiple static directories).  But files like `/favicon.ico` and `/manifest.json` in the `index.html` built from react return a 404 error because they don't exist.

How can I get django to attempt to serve files in the same directory as `index.html` if everything else fails?

Currently I serve `index.html` by doing the following in Django:

In myproject/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('favicon.ico', favicon, name='favicon'),
    ...other-stuff
]
```

In myproject/views.py

```
index = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='myproject/index.html'))
favicon = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='myproject/favicon.ico'))
```

The index works, but favicon doesn't.  So what about the other files that need to be served?  How can I define those files (anywhere from 4-20 files) to be served by uwsgi?

Comment: Nginx/apache should serve these files on prod, not Django.

Comment: @Ivanstarostin and what if it needs to be in a single docker container?

Comment: These things are not related. However I'd suggest to think about separating code with artifacts. In case of docker you can share a volume with a webserver. If your question is related to a specific hosting service - please rephare your original question and mention the service.

Answer (score 0):

`favicon.ico` and `manifest.json` should be in a static directory inside your Django project not inside the react project, because Django will serve them.

Comment: But i can't edit the index.html file to change the reference to /static/favixon.ico since the file is built by node. So how can I set those urls to be treated as static files?

Comment: you should render react ```index.html ``` by using Django

Comment: I am rendering index.html using django.  I copy the built file to the django template folder for django to render it during the CI build.